# Update YTD cell from previous week totals

Tags: excel

I have a table that calculates weekly total for simple timecard. The date fields are derived from the current week function, example the attached shows week 43 with SUNDAY from week 42. When the week ends or some other trigger, the week total is saved in cell C9 and added to the next week when it starts. - I'm sure a database is preferred for this type of results but looking for excel solution.

Cell A2 is populated by: `IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),)=1,TODAY(),TODAY()−WEEKDAY(TODAY()−1,))` and B2 is `=A2+1`

E2 is `WEEKNUM(A2,2)`

Not sure the best practice to achieve this result?

[image]

Comment: I imagine you would have to have a different sheet for each week of the year. There's no way I can think of to automatically take this value in cell C9 and store it somewhere when a week ends and add them up in this desired "year to date" cell.

Comment: if you were to have an individual sheet for each week you could then use a 3D SUM for the YTD cell

Comment: I'm thinking the same, like a 52 week helper table... wondering how/when to populate the weekly total in that table, since the dates are derived dynamically for each week.

Comment: 3D SUM ? I'm not very savvy with excel, can you provide example?

Comment: How would that work on the next week when the dates and weeknum have changed - the 3D SUM would also update to zero in new week?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your solution is the best, but it could work.
I found that your Region and Language configuration for Date assumes that the week starts on Sunday.
You can change the setting to make that Monday is the first day of the week.
Go to **Start -> Control Panel -> Region and Language.**
On Formats tab click on **Additional Settings**.
On Date tab change the **First day of week** to Monday.

Hope it makes your formula behave as you expect.

Comment: What would you suggest as another solution, I'm open to the best way, lets assume my week is changed to Mon-Sun: how would you recommend I proceed?

Comment: Try using my suggestion, I will work later checking if I found an alternate solution.

Comment: You have not given a suggestion for solving my question... fixing the start of week day does not address the year to date totals question?